# SpriteKit particle emitter in a single-page app?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swiftui

1. I've created a ".sks" file.
2. I've configured the effect in the editor.
3. I've added `import SpriteKit` in a swift view file.

Apple's documentation shows this snippet (but I don't know how to use it properly):

`func newSmokeEmitter() -> SKEmitterNode? { return SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "smoke.sks") }`

I've seen [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/11/7/special-effects-skemitternode) and [this](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devfe5e6a005), but they didn't solve my problem either. Does SpriteKit require that you configure your app as a) a game and b) SpriteKit, or can it be done in my single-page app? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're doing this in SwiftUI (as the tags suggest) this might help you: [Using SpriteKit inside SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56615183/8697793) (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367054/8697793) if in SwiftUI 2.0).

Comment: @pawello2222 That question is for a "game" configured for SpriteKit. My app is a single-page app.

Comment: The answer for SwiftUI 2.0 should work in a single-page app as well (if you use SwiftUI 2.0).

Comment: @pawello2222 Ok thanks for your input! I'll look into it.