# changing SpriteKit Scenes in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scene

I have another question related to this topic [Using SpriteKit inside SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615183/using-spritekit-inside-swiftui):

How do you move between different SpriteKit Scenes?

I used to use:

```
let firstScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                let transition = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
                firstScene?.scaleMode = .resizeFill
                scene?.view?.presentScene(firstScene!, transition: transition)
```

How is it done with Swiftui?

Running the above code returns a nil error on GameScene

I am following this in ContentView: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-integrate-spritekit-using-spriteview

```
SpriteView(scene: scene)
.frame(width: 300, height: 400)
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Thanks